# How to start an application when iPad is connected?

Tags: ipad, mojave, automator, script

I would like to start an application (Duet.app) installed on my macOS 10.14.5 whenever I plug my iPad to the USB port. I tried to do it with Automator, but I have no experience.

Comment: If you show what you started with Automator, that might jog someone to suggest a modification.

Answer (score 1):

If it's powered USB, you can install Toolbox.pro to add a condition to check charging status in Shortcuts (https://toolboxpro.app/system look for Battery) to trigger an app opening.